# Google sign in is not able to access the account

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have activated the client services and copy pasted the client id in the code but still clicking on the gsign in button only opens a pop up! and does not proceed further.

Is there any problem in the code,if so can someone please explain what it is! thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Gmail Sign-In</title>
    <!-- <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="ClIENT_ID_HERE">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">Sign In</div>
    <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
    <script>
      function init() {
        gapi.load('auth2', function() { 
          // Ready. 
         
        
        });
      }
      function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
          console.log('User signed out.');
        });
      }

      function onSignIn(parameter){
        console.log(parameter);
      }
    </script>
<!--     <script src="script.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in console or what is actually happening?

Comment: On your local testing server, are you running it with SSL enabled? For IIS and Apache, if you do not have a self-signed SSL cert, and have added your IP to the whitelist, it will block any attempts at authentication.